# Socket.io + TypeScript: Socket.io not listening for new connections

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sockets, socket.io

I've a basic express application which. I'm new to `socket.io`, so i was reading the docs on how to intergrate it with `typescript` and `express` server. Here is what i have for now:

##### `server.ts`

```
import express from "express";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import { createServer, Server as S } from "http";
import router from "./routes";
// ----
const app: express.Application = express();
app.use(router);
const PORT: any = 3001 || process.env.PORT;
const server: S = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {});

io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("we have a new connection");
  console.log(socket.id);
});
//
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`The server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

##### `routes/index.ts`

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";

const router: Router = Router();

router.get("/", (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    name: "backend",
    language: "typescript",
    message: "hello world!",
  });
});

export default router;
```

What i understand is that when i visit the port `3001`. I should see a message on the server console telling me that i have a new connection. Unfortunately there's nothing that is being loged on the console. **What maybe possibly my mistake?**

If i visit http://localhost:3001/, I'm getting the following response

```json
{
"name": "backend",
"language": "typescript",
"message": "hello world!"
}
```

This is because of the `get(/)` route in the `routes/index.ts` file, but no socket.io connection fired after i visited that route.

Answer (score 0):

The websocket is not running on the http protocol but on the websocket protocol. So the URL will be `ws://localhost:3001/`. But socket.io redirects automatically to `ws://localhost:3001/socket.io` when using the client API. The client API is pretty easy to use in my opinion.

You could start with the get-started from socket.io for an easy example; https://socket.io/get-started/chat. This will cover the basics of the server and client which you could then apply to your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this did not work, I've tried the example that you referenced me to and, that's not what i'm looking for exacactly. I want to use the `socket.io-client` to communicate with the server using a react app.